# Get property string name in XAML from property path

Tags: wpf, xaml, nameof

Is there way to get name of property in XAML?

I found there is no support for [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) in XAML.

Something serving like this:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction 
Command="{Binding
    Source={StaticResource SomeViewModel},
    Path=SomeICommandImplementation}" 
CommandParameter={Binding 
    Source={StaticResource SomeViewModel},
    Path=SomeProperty, 
    GetNameOf=True}" />
```

Comment: Did you read their response? "*We have reviewed this and we will not be able to complete this suggestion in the foreseeable future*". So what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there way to get string name of property in XAML.

No, there isn't. XAML is a *markup* language and it has no `nameof` operator defined.

What you could do is to try to implement your own custom `InvokeCommandAction`.

Create a class that derives from `System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction<DependencyObject>`, add the properties of `InvokeCommandAction` (it is `sealed` so you cannot derive from it) and another `GetNameOf` property to it and then override the `Invoke` method to use the `nameof` operator.

Comment: mm8: I conceptually and partially understand your proposition but my properties originates in view model. If I define them at TriggerAction they would exists twice. 

But basically in System.Windows.Interactivity namespace I can find solution since I have information that passing UI elements to its members is MVVM okay.

Comment: You are not supposed to define the view model properties in your custom TriggerAction. You should define the Command, CommandParameter and GetNameOf target properties.